# where and how do I initialise a specific date into date object in java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to initialise a specific date into date object.How can i do that?I tried using the simpledateformat and parse it in from a string,but it gave me a "declare thrown exception" error when i try to run it.

```
Date joinDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String join = "12/05/2012" ;
joinDate = df.parse(join);
```

Comment: Have a look at [Lesson: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: Post your code here. Then we can help you

Comment: Add a try catch block arround your code.

Comment: @jens Will it be ok if I put the try catch block inside the constructor of my object?

Comment: @MrVickiee Yes it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work fine. But you need to add `try-catch` block or `throws` to method

```
try{
    Date joinDate = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String join = "12/05/2012" ;
    joinDate = df.parse(join);
    System.out.println(joinDate);
}catch(ParseException e){
    // handle the ParseException
}
```

Or

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
     Date joinDate = new Date();
     SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
     String join = "12/05/2012" ;
     joinDate = df.parse(join);
     System.out.println(joinDate);
 }
```

Comment: can you give me an example of what should I write to handle the parse exception for the catch part please?

Comment: @MrVickiee you can use a `logger` and print an error message with `Exception`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
    {
        Date joinDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String join = "12/05/2012" ;
        joinDate = df.parse(join);

        System.out.println(joinDate);
    }
```